# Sanity.io studio image cropping and hotspot not working

Tags: sanity

I'm following a NEXT.JS 13 & Sanity tutorial and I'm not being able to crop and set the hotspot for my images in Sanity studio. I can open the cropping/hotspot tool and it shows everything OK, but it's **not letting me slide any of the controls** (see the image below), neither the cropping one, nor the hotspot one.

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. It seems related to production builds, because sanity dev works fine, but either a server build or a local build and start both have the issue. No idea what the cause is

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue using dual input displays (touch and mouse) such as Microsoft's surface line up. Short term fix is to use the touch input or disable the touch input all together. [I have created an issue here.](https://github.com/sanity-io/sanity/issues/4947)